# MSAccess login form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I created a login form but realized that i can log in without entering a password. only a user name. what should i do so as to solve the problem

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdlogin_Click()
    Dim rs As Recordset

    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Account Details", dbOpenSnapshot, dbReadOnly)
    rs.FindFirst "UserName='" & Me.txtusername & "' "
    
    Me.lblusername.Visible = False
    If rs.NoMatch = True Then
        Me.lblusername.Visible = True
        Me.txtusername.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Me.lblpassword.Visible = False
    If rs!Password <> Me.txtpassword Then
        Me.lblpassword.Visible = True
        Me.txtpassword.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
    End If
      DoCmd.OpenForm "Dashboard"
      DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Do not attempt to make a login system in VBA. It is trivial to bypass from a security standpoint and it's needless hassle from a user standpoint. The user already logged in to windows and we know you won't be able to have a login system more secure than that. Just pull the username from Windows, then do whatever user specific things you want with that. EXAMPLE: `userName = Environ("Username")`

Comment: Basically agree with @HackSlash. I pull username with Environ and use it to get record from Users table. If user is not found I just assume they are new valid user and add a record. We do save user initials in some records so new user is asked to provide initials for record (very small office). They never see 'login' form again. Users table defines user permission level for access to some forms and/or buttons.

Answer (score 1):

If txtusername or txtpassword is Null the conditional will fail. Try:

`rs.FindFirst "UserName='" & Nz(Me.txtusername,"") & "'"`

`If rs!Password <> Nz(Me.txtpassword, "") Then`

Or consider:

```
    Dim rs As Recordset
    With Me
    .lblusername.Visible = False
    .lblpassword.Visible = False
    If IsNull(.txtusername) Or IsNull(.txtpassword) Then
        MsgBox "Enter username or password"
    Else
        Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT UserName, Password FROM [Account Details] " & _
             "WHERE UserName='" & .txtusername & "'", dbOpenSnapshot, dbReadOnly)
        If Not rs.BOF And Not rs.EOF Then
            If rs!Password <> .txtpassword Then
                .lblpassword.Visible = True
                .txtpassword.SetFocus
            Else
                DoCmd.OpenForm "Dashboard"
                DoCmd.Close acForm, .Name
            End If
        Else
            .lblusername.Visible = True    
            .txtusername.SetFocus
        End If
    End If
    End With
```